# text[] in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I saw a field `text[]` (text array) in Postgresql.

As far as I understood,it can store multiple text data in a single column.

I tried to read more about it the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-character.html but unfortunately nothing much was there about text[] column type.

So can anyone help me to understand

- How to add a new value to text[] column?
- What will be the resultset when we query to retrieve the values of text[] column?
  **EDIT**
   
  I have a table containing 2 columns **group_name** and **members**. Each time a new person join the group,the *new person's id* should be inserted in the **column members** for that group_name. This is my requirement.A Group can contain **'n' number of members**

  **EDIT 2**

  Pablo is asking me to use two tables instead. May I know how this could be solved by using two different tables? Right now I am using comma(,) to store multiple values separated by comma. Is this method wrong?

Comment: [Array data type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/arrays.html) and [functions and operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html). The PostgreSQL manual is quite good (once you know what you're looking for of course).

Comment: @muistooshort Can u send me any reference where proper examples are provided. I dont find this manual very much friendly to learn

Comment: I learned it all straight from the manual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To insert new values just do:

```
insert into foo values (ARRAY['a', 'b']);
```

Assuming you have this table:

```
create table foo (a text[]);
```

Every time you do a `select a from foo` you will have a column of type array:

```
db1=> select a from foo;
   a   
-------
 {a,b}
(1 row)
```

If you want a specific element from the array, you need to use subscripts (arrays in PostgreSQL are 1-based):

```
db=> select a[1] from foo;
 a 
---
 a
(1 row)
```

Be careful when choosing an array datatype for your PostgreSQL tables. Make sure you don't need a **child table** instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot:) I have a small doubt. I give query as db1=> select a from foo; so i ll get in my resultset {a,b,c,d,e}. What if i want to check whether a character(random character) is present in this set?

Comment: Can long strings be stored in text[] column type? Will it have any performance or Storage issue?

Comment: Yes, you can store long text (string) in `text[]` columns. My recommendation is that if you are not 100% what are those array for, avoid them. Use plain `text` columns unless you have a really good reason to use arrays. If you want to check for a random character inside array, take a look at array functions in PostgreSQL.

Comment: I want to store multiple values in a column. So which is better? By multiple values I mean it can be large number(more than 500 in a column)

Comment: Did you consider using a separate table for those 500 numbers? What's the semantics of that column?

Comment: What do you mean? I have a table containing 2 columns group_name and members. Each time a new person join the group,the new person's id should be inserted in the column "members" for that group_name. This is my requirement.A Group can contain 'n' number of members.

Comment: Then my suggestion is: DO NOT USE AN ARRAY COLUMN. Just use two tables: `groups` and `group_members`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11380/discussion-between-suraj-and-pablo-santa-cruz)